# VSCode OSX TERMINAL Delete Right From Cursor

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how to delete a word going to the end of the line (right) in the VSCode Terminal (not editor)?

This works fine doing `shift+ctrl+rightArrow` in the Editor and I've mapped the same key-binding in iterm2 which labels this behavior I'm looking for as "Move End of Selection Right By Word".

I would love to `shift+ctrl+arrow` in the TERMINAL to select my text like I can in iterm2.

I've searched and searched and have come up short. I'm using `iterm.app` in VSCode as well as setting my defaultProfile.osx to `zsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these keybindings that I know work in Git Bash (in keybindings.json):

```
{
    "key": "alt+delete",     // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { 
      "text": "\u001b\u007f"   // delete from cursor to word left start
    },   
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},

{
    "key": "ctrl+delete",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "\u001bd"  // delete from cursor to word end right
    }, 
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

These are sending controls sequences to the terminal.  I don't think there is any built-in commands to do this.

Comment: Thank you! Using "key": "shift+cmd+right", & "key": "shift+cmd+left", respectively, gave me what was I looking for!